# Project Linker for MonoDevelop?

Tags: monodevelop

Does there exist something akin to [Project Linker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921108(v=pandp.20).aspx) for MonoDevelop?

Comment: Not yet – please see the comments on the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144762/use-mono-for-android-on-with-mono.

Comment: I don't use Project Linker, but what does it have that [MD](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Linker) lacks? CHEERS!