# Use Mono for android on with Mono

Tags: windows, mono, xamarin.android, monodevelop, xamarin

It looks really easy to switch MonoDevelop's compiler to Mono tools instead of .NET – you just need to pick a different framework under settings of the IDE.

However, after switching to Mono and getting the project compiling by Mono tools, Mono for android no longer seems to be an available framework (i.e. the reference to it in the Android project turns red). Obviously, the build fails with tons of errors like Android.XXX.YYY is not a class or namespace name, etc.

Is there a way to install Mono for android on a Windows machine so that it is available to Mono tools and usable from Monodevelop running on Mono?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Mono for Android uses the MSBuild build system, and installs custom build tasks and frameworks into the MSBuild extension directories. Mono's implementation of MSBuild (xbuild) has separate extension directories. It might be possible to copy the targets and extensions across but you'd probably run into other issues, as it's completely untested.

In general on Windows I'd recommend using the MS/.NET toolchain in MonoDevelop unless you have a really good reason to use the Mono toolchain. Note that you can *run* with Mono even if you compile with .NET, using the *Run->Run with...* menu.

Comment: Well, the reason if simple: I want to share the code between MonoTouch and Mono for android, and PCL features are not really convinient to work with. On Monodevelop Mac PCL projects are compiled used monotouch compiler (you helped to find out how to do it :), but on windows they are build as true PCL, which limits the features available to common code dramatically. AFAIK there is no anything like dependent projects in MonoDevelop which might work in the same way as PCL ones on Mac do?

Comment: No, there is no project linker, though you can manually share files between projects. In fact, MD makes that quite easy with the "Add files from folder" command.

Comment: Alternatively you could use a Mono for Android project, and reference it as a dll (not a project reference) from a MonoTouch project. Although this is pretty hacky, it should work fine as long as you only reference BCL assemblies and use classes that also exist in MonoTouch.

Comment: Yeah, but every time a new file added to a folder makes it unavadoable to re-add everything...

Comment: And referencing DLL won't make it rebuild itself on demand, it will be neccessary to manually rebuild the common assembly :(